# Spring: No message found under code for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring

applicationContext-Service.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list><value>messages</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have messages_en_US.properties under /src/messages_en_US.properties

```
registerForm.passwordNotMatch=Password does not match.
```

This is line of code is bringing up the error:

```
binding.addError(new FieldError(REGISTER_FORM, "passwordNotMatch", messageSource.getMessage("registerForm.passwordNotMatch", null, locale)));
```

Error: No message found under code 'registerForm.passwordNotMatch' for locale 'en_US'.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Where is `applicationContext-Service.xml` declared?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

does it work if you change  to:

```
classpath:messages
```

?

I had the experience that if using `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, in jsp  will not find the properties file. adding `classpath:` before the `basename` solved my problem.

Well even though was my project managed by maven, I think you can give it a try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For those using `@Bean` annotation for `bundleMessageSource`.
Add the **name** for `@Bean`.

> name="messageSource"

Use the same name we used to create the `MessageSource` object in `@RestController` class

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world-internationalized")
    public String helloWorldInternationalized(@RequestHeader(name = "Accept-Language", required = false) Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, locale);
    }
}
```

Then in the `@SpringBootApplication` class

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")//wont work without the bean name
public ResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Referred [this link](https://www.concretepage.com/questions/380)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried `classpath:` but it didn't make a difference. Ended up putting in a carriage return on the last line of my properties file (so the cursor sits on the next line, which is the end of the file).

Also, if you're using Maven and you place your properties file like so: `/resources/xxxx.properties`, the resource directory is automatically pulled into your generated war, so `classpath:` is not necessary.

Comment: to be precise, the directory should be `PROJECT_BASE/src/main/resources/`, just to avoid confusion

Answer (score -2):

I think instead of `<property name="basenames">` it should be `<property name="basename">`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `setBasename()` accepts a single `String`, `setBasenames()` accepts an array of `String`s.